# Turning off indentation for goto labels

Tags: indentation, cc-mode

I'm using the `ellemtel` style for my C code.  This mode indents goto labels like this:

```
void f(int x)
{ 
  if (x) {
    goto LABEL0;
  } else { 
    goto LABEL1;
  }
  LABEL0:
  printf("x is zero\n");
  return;
  LABEL1:
  printf("x isn't zero\n");
  return;
}
```

I'd like to turn off indentation for goto labels entirely.  So that my code would look like this:

```
void f(int x)
{ 
  if (x) {
    goto LABEL0;
  } else { 
    goto LABEL1;
  }
LABEL0:
  printf("x is zero\n");
  return;
LABEL1:
  printf("x isn't zero\n");
  return;
}
```

The documentation for C-mode wasn't very helpful nor was a Google search.

Comment: The question might be a duplicate. Maybe search for tag [indentation] to check. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation is configured in [`c-offsets-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#c_002doffsets_002dalist), which is set by a [style](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#Styles). You need to change the indentation for the `label` [syntactic symbol](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#Syntactic-Symbols) from the default (2, unchanged in the `ellemtel` style) to 0.

[Define your own style](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#Adding-Styles) based on `ellemtel` with your preferences and [make it the default](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#index-c_002ddefault_002dstyle). Based on your sample, it should also change [`c-basic-offset`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#Customizing-Indentation) to 2 (from 3 in `ellemtel`).

```
(defconst tkf-c-style
  '("ellemtel"
    (c-basic-offset . 2)
    (c-offsets-alist (label . 0))))
(defun my-after-load-cc-styles ()
  (c-add-style "tkf" tkf-c-style))
(eval-after-load "cc-styles" (my-after-load-cc-styles))
(setq c-default-style "tkf")
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thanks.